# Can possible Path-Based routing with Route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

Can possible Path-Based routing with Route53.
I have two service 1. react application on s3 CloudFront and 2. Nodejs service API on lambda.
I want it as xyz.abc.com/ which serve react application and xyz.abc.com/share which can serve nodejs API

Comment: How did it go? Is it still unclear what you can do?

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible with Route53 as it is  a DNS web service, which means it does not take into account any url paths. You must do this through your application, for example using CloudFront where you can define [origin path](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesOriginPath).

Comment: thank you for replying 
how to do with CloudFront? can you please share me quick links
I tried to add Web ACL which redirect me on my nodejs service but now I need to pass query parameters. 
how to I can ?